# remove part of string after 4th slash in php

Tags: php

I have an array which is contains links and trying to edit those links. Trying to cut links after 4th slash.

```
  [0]=>
  string(97) "https://www.nowhere.com./downtoalley/?iad2=sumai-pickup&argument=CH4fRVnN&dmai=shimokita4040/outline"
  [1]=>
  string(105) "https://www.example.com./wowar-waseda/?iad2=sumai-pickup&argument=CH4fRVnN&dmai=shinjuku-w25861/outline"
  [2]=>
  string(91) "https://www.hey.com./gotoashbourn/?iad2=sumai-pickup&argument=CH4fRVnN&dmai=kinuta7429/outline"
```

expected output is like this:

```
  [0]=>
  string(97) "https://www.nowhere.com./downtoalley/"
  [1]=>
  string(105) "https://www.example.com./wowar-waseda/"
  [2]=>
  string(91) "https://www.hey.com./gotoashbourn/"
```

Lengths are different, so I can't use `strtok` any other options for this?

Comment: Have you tried using `implode` and `explode`? Consider getting one value of array and set to variable like this `$parts  = explode('/', 'https://www.nowhere.com./downtoalley/?iad2=sumai-pickup&argument=CH4fRVnN&dmai=shimokita4040/outline');` and output will be on  `$output = implode('/', array_slice($parts, 0, 3));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace everything in each string after the fourth `/` with nothing using this regex

```
^(([^/]*/){4}).*$
```

which looks for 4 sets of non-`/` characters followed by a `/`, collecting that text in capture group 1; and then replacing with `$1` which gives only the text up to the 4th `/`:

```
$strings = array("https://www.nowhere.com./downtoalley/?iad2=sumai-pickup&argument=CH4fRVnN&dmai=shimokita4040/outline",
"https://www.example.com./wowar-waseda/?iad2=sumai-pickup&argument=CH4fRVnN&dmai=shinjuku-w25861/outline",
"https://www.hey.com./gotoashbourn/?iad2=sumai-pickup&argument=CH4fRVnN&dmai=kinuta7429/outline");
print_r(array_map(function ($v) { return preg_replace('#^(([^/]*/){4}).*$#', '$1', $v); }, $strings));
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => https://www.nowhere.com./downtoalley/
    [1] => https://www.example.com./wowar-waseda/
    [2] => https://www.hey.com./gotoashbourn/ 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/vYoau)

Answer (score 2):

Try following code:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
0 => "https://www.nowhere.com./downtoalley/?iad2=sumai-pickup&argument=CH4fRVnN&dmai=shimokita4040/outline",
1 => "https://www.example.com./wowar-waseda/?iad2=sumai-pickup&argument=CH4fRVnN&dmai=shinjuku-w25861/outline",
2 => "https://www.hey.com./gotoashbourn/?iad2=sumai-pickup&argument=CH4fRVnN&dmai=kinuta7429/outline");

$resultArray = array();
foreach($arr as $str) {
    array_push($resultArray, current(explode("?",$str)));   
}
print_r($resultArray);

?>
```

You can test this code [here](http://codepad.org/gJvH3pMn)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct function to achieve this. You can follow PHP code as below:

```
$explodingLimit = 4;
$string = "https://www.nowhere.com./downtoalley/?iad2=sumai-pickup&argument=CH4fRVnN&dmai=shimokita4040/outline";
$stringArray = explode ("/", $string);
$neededElements = array_slice($stringArray, 0, $explodingLimit);
echo implode("/", $neededElements);
```

I have made this for one element which you can use for you array. Also you can add last `'/'` if you need that. Hope it helps you.